# how to specify the method signature for a method with nested Object as parameter in jni

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a java class calling a native function through jni.The java class consists of the following method.

```
public void indexToEs(ArrayList<LinkedHashMap <String , Object>> list) throws IOException 
    {
            IndexingLogDataToES indexingobj = new IndexingLogDataToES();
            indexingobj.indexLogData(list , logName, client);
    }
```

Now how should i specify the method signature in order to get the method Id of this method in my native function.
i tried the following but it didnt work.i get method id as null.

```
jmethodID indexMethod = env->GetMethodID(callingClass , "indexToEs" , "(Ljava/util/ArrayList(Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;);)V");
    if( indexMethod == NULL )
    {
        cout << "index method not found" << endl ;
        return ;  
    }
    else cout << "index method found" << endl ;
```

Where calling class is the reference to the class calling.How should i do this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)
the type parameters don't get compiled into the class file.

Therefore, the method `void indexToEs(ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,Object>>)`
has the same signature as the method `void indexToEs(ArrayList)` would have.

That means, the method signature is just `(Ljava/util/ArrayList;)V` and you should call

```
env->GetMethodID(callingClass , "indexToEs" , "(Ljava/util/ArrayList)V");
```

Comment: thanks for the response , i tried i but still getting the id as null

Comment: Regardless, it is the correct answer `javap -s callingClass | grep "indexToEs" -A 2 | grep "descriptor"`